# Where do I find the library's files after building Polycode with MSVC 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, polycode

I downloaded the polycode-master from Github

I ran `cmake` as suggested in the `BUILD.md`

And then I built the `ALL_BUILD` project from the `PolycodeDependencies.sln`with MSVC 2013

Where do I now find the DLL and LIB files and how do I set up a new Project to use Polycode?

EDIT: I now headed over to [http://polycode.org/download/](http://polycode.org) and downloaded the zip-file with the binaries but I still dont know how to use them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've built the Dependcies you need to build the real Polycode stuff - that's described a bit further down in `Build.md`.

After you've built `ALL_BUILD` in the Polycode.sln you'll find the C++ libraries in `Release/Windows/Framework/Core/lib`.

To use those libs you might want to start with the Examples in the `Release/Windows/Framework/Examples` folder.

To start your own project either use the Template in the Template folder or use the [PolycodeProjectGenerator](http://github.com/fodinabor/PolycodeProjectGenerator) (disclaimer: I'm the author of the last one)

Hope this helps a bit..

Oh and don't forget to build the install targets of dependencies and Polycode!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the build directory you specified when running cmake. There should be a subfolder called bin or something similar that has the binaries.

Comment: Couldnt find anything :/